# Drupal 7 - module for showing single aggregated db value

Tags: drupal

I am trying to find one or more Drupal 7 modules which can help me handling the number of participants to an event.

I have a webform that enables sign up for an event:

- Where the event is limited to a certain number of people
- That contains a field for registering the number of people you are signing up for.

What I need is to present the number of signed up participants in the webform or at least on the same page. I can find this number in the MySQL database by summing up the 'data' column in table 'webform_submitted_data', where node id and component id matches the webform and number field.

I have not been able to find a module in Drupal 7 that can help me with this. Is it possible without writing a custom module or hack existing code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably need is [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator), as it can also  process Webform submissions. Please read more about it on the module page and its README.txt in the module itself.

To present it on the same page without a custom module, you will need to learn how use the webform inconjunction with maybe a block to display the results.

Note that there is a separate [SE forum for Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), where you can ask specific questions. But if you have issues with the module, post a question on the module's issues queue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Z Z ! I am currently looking into using Computed Field, but will check out Views Aggregator Plus if it Computed Field doesn't work out for me.

Comment: Have you solved  it?

Comment: I ended up creating a content type based on webform and added computed fields using the Computed Field module. I then added Javascript to the content type body, enabling me to conditionally control field visibility. Not very sexy, but it works and gives the customer the functionality they need. Thanks for the tip, though :)